# Loss function not showing

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to start trying my hand at neural networks and found keras to be very simple syntactically. My set up is X_train is an array of shape (3516, 6)
and y_train is of shape (3516,)

X_train looks like this:

```
[[ 888.          900.5         855.          879.311       877.00266667
   893.5008    ]
 [ 875.          878.5         840.          880.026       874.56933333
   890.7948    ]
 [ 860.          870.          839.5         880.746       870.54333333
   887.6428    ]....]
```

it is an input of 6 pieces of financial data to predict one output. I know its not going to be accurate but it is to get me going on something at least before I get on to RNNs
my problem is that the loss function at every epoch shows nan, accuracy shows 0%, validation_accuracy shows zero percent as if to say that data isnt even being passed through the model, I mean even if its a poor model with poor inputs even that should be represented by a large loss right? here is the model:(see below)

anyway guys I am sure that I am doing something wrong and would really appreciate you guys' input
many thanks 
S

EDIT: FULL WORKING CODE:

```
def load_data(keyword):

    df = pd.read_csv('%s_x.csv' %keyword)
    df2 = pd.read_csv('%s_y.csv' %keyword)

    df2 = df2['label']

    try:
        df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis = 1, inplace=True)
    except:
        print('wouldnt let drop unnamed column')

    X = df.as_matrix()
    y = df2.as_matrix()

    X_len = len(X)
    test_size = 0.2
    test_split = int(test_size * X_len)
    X_train = X[:-test_split]
    y_train = y[:-test_split]

    X_test = X[-test_split:]
    y_test = y[-test_split:]

def keras():
    model = Sequential( [
        Dense(input_dim=3, output_dim=3),
        Dense(output_dim=60, activation='linear'),
        core.Dropout(p=0.1),
        Dense(60, activation='linear'),
        core.Dropout(p=0.1),
        Dense(1, activation='linear')
    ])
    return model


def training(epoch):
    #  start the program off by loading some data into it
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = load_data('admiral')
    y_train = y_train.reshape(len(y_train), 1)
    y_test = y_test.reshape(len(y_test), 1)


    model = keras()


    # optimizer will go into the compile function
    # RMSpop is apparently a pretty decent choice for recurrent neural networks although we will start it on a simple nn too.
    rms = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho = 0.9, epsilon =1e-08)


    model.compile(optimizer= rms, loss='mean_squared_error ', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=epoch, batch_size =500, validation_split=0.01)

    score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=50)
    print(score)

training(300)
```

Comment: Can you post the full working code?

Comment: here you go man the code is up... I was thinking that it would be because of the exploding gradient problem, but the thing is that three of the six input values are 10, 15, 20 day rolling averages of the target value so with that link with the label, surely it should still show a loss even if it is big ?..

Comment: hey anmol, shrunk the inputs to just the 10,15,20 day rolling average of the close value and it is working now, the loss is very high and accuracy is 0.0034 for every epoch n or there abouts, it hit 0.69 once but either way it is working now, I think its time to build an LSTM network basically,

Comment: That's great! You can either delete the question or answer it yourself so that others will be able to benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accuracy really low because it doesnt make sense to show accuracy, for a regression problem, it is more for classification

data was being passed through it was just so low it was a Nan question answered